# Material design framework

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a Backbone App (the API will be in Java / Jersey). We want to use Material Design for the app.
Requirements:

- Material design framework should be fast (its vague i know - but still a requirement)
- It should be mature enough, that the codebase of the framework won't change completly
- good documentation

We thought about using materializecss (http://materializecss.com/) but i'm wondering if it is mature enough.

Please recommend a framework that you have seen in production.

Comment: I am not going give answer because I don't have enough experience working on front-end domain. The MaterialzeCSS is on __alpha__ release. So, we can indicate that project is under development stage right now. You can contribute to them via [their Github](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize) repository. I found [some alternatives](http://www.sitepoint.com/top-5-material-design-frameworks-use-2015/) on internet, though. I give you a suggestion too, if you are looking for better alternatives than this one, please give us detail of your requirement. For example, comparing with this.

Comment: Fabian, we can't help you if you don't say what you want to do with it. Please detail all of your requirements. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Sorry to tell you, bat your question goes beyond the scope of this site – which is to find/recommend software for specific needs, not to evaluate software you name. If you're askin for alternatives, please take a look at [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185): you need to name your requirements explicitly (but it would be on-topic then).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I just took the liberty and rewrote the question to bring it on topic for this site. I'm unsure about how clear it is to the domain experts but I leave it to them to decide that. If you feel I have altered your question too far, you can rollback the edit from the edit history (click on the "edited X min ago" link)